# Function to left rotate a given array item n position to left - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, function, jasmine2.0

I'm doing some exercises on JavaScript and I came into a question that asks to rotate arrays item to the left with a given *n rotation steps*. The exercises are tested with Jasmine. Tried several method but none are meeting the precondition:

```
it("Arrays: Rotation Gauche", function () {
     // DESCRIPTION:
     // A left rotation operation on an array shifts each element
     // from the array to the left. For example, if left rotations are
     // done on the array [1,2,3,4,6], the array would become [3,4,5,1,2]
     //
     // Given an array of integers a, do n left rotations on
     //  the array. The function returns the updated array.
    function rotateLeft(a, n) {
      // TODO: implement the function as described in DESCRIPTION
    let len = 0,j=0
    var b =[]
    len = a.length
    for (let i = n; i < len; i++){
        b[j] = a[i]
        j++
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        b[j] = a[i]
        j++
    }
    return b;

  }

    // Jasmin unit tests
    let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6];
    let expected = [3, 4, 5, 1, 2];
    expect(rotateLeft(input, 4)).toBe(expected);
    input = [41, 73,89,7,10,1,59,58,84,77,77,97,58,1,86,58,26,10,86,51];
    expected = [7,97, 58, 1, 86, 58, 26, 10, 86, 51, 41, 73, 89, 7, 10, 1, 59, 58, 84, 77]
    expect(rotateLeft(input, 10)).toBe(expected);
    input = [98,67,35,1,74,79,7,26,54,63,24,17,32,81];
    expected = [26, 54, 63, 24, 17, 32, 81, 98, 67, 35 ,1 ,74, 79, 7]
    expect(rotateLeft(input, 7)).toBe(expected);
  });
```

My last attempt is below the TODO comment.

And obviously the tests aren't passing. I tried several approaches without success. It's just an exercise, so I would like some guidance.

Thanks

Comment: Problem description and test cases don't quite make sense to me. `[1,2,3,4,6], the array would become [3,4,5,1,2]`. OK... where is the 5 coming from and where did 6 go? I expect that `[1,2,3,4,6]` rotated 4 to the left would give `[6, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. What's a "table" in this context? Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Well,I also thought it was a mistake then thought it could be part of the test? But tests fail even after changing that to [1,2,3,4,5]. So my solution is wrong. Oh that's Google translate, it's array. Edited

Comment: I think you should seek clarification from whomever gave you the assignment. Given that the 5 is a typo, I'd think left rotations gives `[3, 4, 6, 1, 2]`, not 4.

Comment: So the attempt I made could be good then? It's on codepen, I could give the url if you don't mind?

Comment: "The updated array is returned". maybe you should edit a in place and return it ? Also you have two consecutive 77 in input but not in expected output. Review your test cases ?

Comment: There are definitely errors both in questions and test cases. Thanks for your interest